# Correct word choice for "get a new subset from set"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am trying to choose a title. 
I have a big data set and I will get subsets of this data set using statistical techniques (random sampling etc.).

Which one of the following is correct? If more than one is suitable, is there a nuance between them?

- create subset data sets
- construct subset data sets
- get new subset data set

I am not a native speaker; therefore if all of them are wrong, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: A *subset* is still a *set*, and if it was created from a *data set*, it's still a *data set*. So I wouldn't bother with the word(s) *"dataset"* at all. I think *"create"* is better than *"construct"*, and *"get new subset"* sounds like an inline comment to program code, not really suitable for general-purpose writing.

Comment: I thought I'd seen a verb form of the word "subset", as in "we subset the data", but I can't find a reference to it, so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: You are getting good answers here, but if this is writing intended for an audience of statisticians it may also be wise to consult http://stats.stackexchange.com/, since they will be well-versed in the most common usage patterns for their field.

Comment: *Subset* is perfectly valid as a verb, in a technical context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write for example

> Using random sampling, we **obtain** these data subsets.

The verbs *create*, *construct* and *get* are alright but sound awkward.

*Create* suggests that something is produced from scratch, *construct* suggests that an elaborate procedure exists to produce something, and *obtain* suggests that something is produced from something else.

Comment: Actually : there exists data pre-processing steps. But I do not consider them to be too elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe 'extract' captures the fact that you're processing the original data to obtain the subsets e.g. "Using random sampling, we extracted the following subsets...".

Comment: Are you using extract as "To take by selection"

Comment: Yep, pretty much, although it could be thought of as more informal as in "extracting the juice from an orange"

Answer (score 3):

I would use `extract`, meaning "[to draw forth](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extract)".

Also, saying "subset data sets" is redundant. The word "subsets" already includes "sets", and basically means "a smaller set from a larger set." So, I would describe what you are extracting as `data subsets`, as in the following examples:

> Given the original data, we extracted various subsets based on the
>   following criteria...
>
> We extracted these data subsets from the original study...
>
> We used random sampling to extract a subset of data...

Answer (score 2):

All of them are *correct*, except that *get a new...* seems more natural than *get new...*.  Also note that assemblies derived via random sampling are often referred to as *drawn* rather than *created*  (e.g.: "Eight sets/subsets/datasets/samples were drawn from the population") to underpin the notion they are random rather than deterministically constructed.

Comment: Since drawn is not a verb, can I use "draw subsets from data".

Comment: Yes; for example, "We drew eight subsets from the population", "We randomly selected eight subsets from the population", "We randomly constructed eight subsets from a thousand random members of the population", "We draw random subsets in the following way: ...", etc.  Exact wording must vary to accord with circumstances.

Comment: Point of clarification: "were drawn" *is* a verb. But jwpat is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you mean title? Because it seems you talk about an abstract. A title would sound like "Creation of a subset...".
Indeed, *extract* is commonly used in sampling, and you can also simply say *we sample a subset* or *we take/draw a sample*
*Get* is informal and is not preferable in formal literature.
*Construct* has a nuance of elaboration, often as a result of an algorithm or procedure in which all steps are given.
*Obtain* is very common and has a formal touch.

Answer (score 1):

By far the most common term I have come across that is used to convey this meaning is '*extract*'. I would suggest it on the strength of its familiarity, precedence and also for being very unambiguous.

There could be a better term, though, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the phrase "collect a subset from the dataset."

Another prviously mentioned answer "extract subsets" would be appropriate.

If you're looking for a title: "Extracting Subsets: Various Statistical Techniques" would probably be appropriate for your assignment.

A subset is a portion of a set, and if you're collecting it from a dataset, then the term data set subset is incredibly redundant.

Answer (score 1):

When speaking precisely about any type of set, a given set is also defined as a "**Subset**" of *itself*.

If you want to precisely describe a *partial* dataset, you would instead refer to a "**Proper Subset**" — so perhaps one might say you will be "*selecting and/or extracting **(proper) subsets** from the entire dataset.*"

But omitting "proper" is perfectly fine, it's just if you need to specifically emphasize the non-entirety of it for some reason.